# How to assign some key values from a function returning dictionary to another dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have three dictionaries; fruits, vegetables, and total. Two of the dictionaries are modified in two different functions; and the same two dictionaries are a subset of the total dictionary. The functions return the modified dictionaries. How can I assign part of the keys in the function returned dictionary to a part in the total dictionary as shown in the MWE.

**MWE**

```
def get_fruits(x):
    fruits = {'apples'       : 0, 'oranges'      : 0, 'bananas'      : 0, 'strawberries' : 0, 'blueberries'  : 0}
    if x == 'apples':
        fruits['apples'] += 1
    elif x == 'oranges':
        fruits['oranges'] += 1
    elif x == 'bananas':
        fruits['bananas'] += 1
    return fruits
def get_vegetables(x):
    vegetables = {'carrots'   : 0, 'potatoes'  : 0, 'onions'    : 0, 'garlics'   : 0, 'gingers'   : 0}
    if x == 'carrots':
        vegetables['carrots'] += 1
    elif x == 'potatoes':
        vegetables['potatoes'] += 1
    elif x == 'onions':
        vegetables['onions'] += 1
    return vegetables
total = {
            'apples'       : 0, 'oranges'      : 0, 'grapes'       : 0, 'bananas'      : 0, 'strawberries' : 0, 'blueberries'  : 0,
            'carrots'      : 0, 'potatoes'     : 0, 'onions'       : 0, 'gingers'      : 0, 'cucumbers'    : 0, 'garlics'      : 0
        }

total['apples'], total['oranges'], total['bananas'] = get_fruits('apples')['apples','oranges','bananas']
```

In other words, I need the function get_fruits to update only three keys; apples, oranges, and bananas; how can this be done in Python?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just using `collections.Counter`

Lets simplify your example as well:

- remove if/else key examples
- make fruits / vegetables global sets
- use counter so we can do `x += y`

```py
from collections import Counter

FRUITS = {'apples', 'oranges', 'bananas', 'strawberries', 'blueberries'}
VEGETABLES = {'carrots', 'potatoes', 'onions', 'garlics', 'gingers'}

def get_fruits(x):
    ret = Counter()
    if x in FRUITS:
        ret[x] += 1
    return ret

def get_vegetables(x):
    ret = Counter()
    if x in VEGETABLES:
        ret[x] += 1
    return ret

total = Counter({x: 0 for x in FRUITS | VEGETABLES})
total += get_fruits('apples')
```

There are other changes that could be made as well, but I assume you already simplified out some code that uses the fact that there are different functions here.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer to the question is the `update` function, which will update one dictionary with values from another (leaving other `key: value` pairs unchanged).

```
>>> total = {'apples': 0, 'oranges': 0, 'carrots': 0, 'onions': 0}
>>> total.update({'apples': 1, 'oranges': 2})
>>> total
{'apples': 1, 'oranges': 2, 'carrots': 0, 'onions': 0}
```

So you could do:

```
total.update(get_fruits('apples'))
```

to update `total` with all of the values returned by `get_fruits('apples')`.

To filter a dictionary you can do a comprehension, e.g.:

```
{k: v for k, v in get_fruits('apples').items() if k in {'apples', 'oranges', 'bananas'}}
```

Note that your `get_fruits` and `get_vegetables` functions do not actually do the thing you describe them as doing; they create the dictionaries from scratch each time rather than modifying them, so you'll always just get back a dict with 1 of whatever you passed as the parameter.  To modify the dictionary and increment the count you'd want to pass the same dictionary in each time as an argument, e.g.:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import Dict

def add_item(item: str, inventory: Dict[str, int]) -> None:
    inventory[item] += 1

fruits: Dict[str, int] = defaultdict(int)
vegetables: Dict[str, int] = defaultdict(int)

add_item('apples', fruits)
add_item('apples', fruits)
add_item('carrots', vegetables)

total: Dict[str, int] = {}
total.update(fruits)
total.update(vegetables)
# total: 2 apples, 1 carrots
```

etc.

Comment: The filter function on the dictionary (`{k: v for k, v in get_fruits('apples').items() if k in {'apples', 'oranges', 'bananas'}}`) does the job right, but when I assign the values as `total['apples'], total['oranges'], total['bananas'] = {k: v for k, v in get_fruits('apples').items() if k in {'apples', 'oranges', 'bananas'}}`. The total dictionary has 'apples ': 'apples', 'oranges': 'oranges' ..., i.e. the keys are assigned.

Comment: Yes; don't do that.  You can't destructure a dict as a tuple and get the values as well as the keys out of it.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite good answers above. If I may have understood your request then are you trying to do something like the following?

````py
total = {'fruits': {'apples' : 0, 
                    'oranges': 0, 
                    'bananas': 0, 
                    'strawberries' : 0, 
                    'blueberries'  : 0,
                   },
         'vegetables': {'carrots': 0, 
                        'potatoes'  : 0, 
                        'onions'    : 0, 
                        'garlics'   : 0, 
                        'gingers'   : 0,
                       }
        }

def get_fruits(x):
    if x in ('apples', 'oranges', 'bananas'):
        total['fruits'][x] += 1

def get_vegetables(x):
    if x in ('carrots', 'potatoes', 'onions'):
        total['vegetables'][x] += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":

    fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas']

    for fruit in fruits:
        get_fruits(fruit)

    for fruit in fruits:
        print(total['fruits'][fruit])

# You should see an increase in the fruit count

    for fruit in fruits:
        get_fruits(fruit)

    for fruit in fruits:
        print(total['fruits'][fruit])```
````